# Finding Mean and Standard Error of x̅

Tags: statistics, sampling

Mean wage per hour for all $5000$ employees working for a large company is $£15$ per hour with a standard deviation of $£4$. Let $x̅$ be the mean wage per hour for a random sample of employees selected from this company. 
Find the Mean and Standard Error of $x̅$ for a sample size of $25$ and $256$.

As $25$ is less than $30$, what does that mean? Do I have to go around the two numbers differently because one is above 30 and one is below?
Thanks.

Comment: The $30$ you seem to vaguely remember is probably related to an old rule-of-thumb about using a $t$-test where you do not know the mean and variance of a population.  It is no longer necessary given computers rather than tables.  It is irrelevant to your question here, where you do know the population mean and variance.  A slightly different issue here is the finite population if you are sampling without replacements, but the impact will be small when considering $25$ or $256$ out of $5000$

Comment: Great thanks so much. Do you know how to find the mean and standard error for the two values? I thought i was given the mean.

Comment: Have you been taught the expectation and variance of the sample mean?

Answer (score 1):

**Comments:** Let me guess: you've rushed to tackle the homework problems before
studying the supporting text material or lecture notes. Please do the reading first. In particular, start by looking for the terminology and formulas in my first
paragraph below and in @Henry's Comments.

It is safe to assume 5000 is "essentially infinite" compared with $n = 25.$
Then $\mu = £15$ and $E(\bar X) =\mu = £15$. Also, $\sigma = £4$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n} = £0.80.$ Then £0.80 is the *standard error* of the sample mean $\bar X.$

Because $n = 256 < \frac{1}{10}(5000)= 500,$ most authors would say it is OK to answer using the same method as for $n = 25.$ [Fussier authors would say that the 'finite population correction' should be used to find $SD(\bar X).$ You can google that, if it's not in your book.]

To reiterate @Henry's Comment, "30" has absolutely nothing to do with either part.